# Duplicated List of DropdownList when ajax update?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a **Ajax Jquery** function:

```
function UpdateValue() {
$(document.body).on("change",".quantity", function () {
    var ProID = $(this).attr("data");
    var Quantity = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", url: "/Cart/UpdateValue",
        data: { ProID: ProID, quantity: Quantity },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#cartbox").html(data);
        }
    }
        );
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
});
}
```

call UpdateValue in Cart Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult UpdateValue(Cart cart,int ProID, int quantity)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(),
                                           Value = i.ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.Items = items;
        Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID 
                                                                   == ProID);
        if (product != null)
        {
            cart.UpdateItem(product, quantity);
        }
        CartIndexViewModel ptview = new CartIndexViewModel { Cart = cart,
                                                                 ReturnUrl = "/" };
        return PartialView(ptview);
    }
```

When the ajax function success, it returns **UpdateValue View**. But the `Dropdown` List always changes the same in each row. How can i pass the selected value from the Index View after ajax update?

Here is my UpdateValue View Code:

```
<table id="cartbox">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tên hàng</th>
                <th>Số lượng</th>
                <th>Đơn giá</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="width:70px">Thành tiền</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>@line.Product.Name
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("Quantity", new SelectList(ViewBag.Items as System.Collections.IList, "Value", "Text", line.Quantity), new { data = line.Product.ProductID, @class = "quantity" })</td>
                    <td style="color:#3A9504;margin-left:3px">@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", line.Product.Price)</td>
                    <td>@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", (line.Quantity * line.Product.Price))</td>
                    <td align="center" style="width:10px"><a href="@Url.Action("RemoveFromCart","Cart",new{ProID= line.Product.ProductID, returnUrl= Request.Url.PathAndQuery})"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/delete.png")" style="padding-right:10px" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr style="border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#DFDFDF;border-top-width:1px;">
                <td colspan="3" align="right" style="border-right-color:#808080;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1px;text-align:right"><b>Tổng tiền:</b></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><b>@string.Format("{0:00,0 VNĐ}", Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue())</b></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then your problem is that after updating the data in the dropdown list you lose the selection in that dropdown list?

If so then you would need to add this to your `success` handler in JavaScript:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#cartbox").html(data);
    $("#cartbox").find(".quantity").val(Quantity);
}
```

Comment: No, the selection not changed after i continue change value in another row. It change all  dropdownlist each row with the same value. I have tried `$("#cartbox").find(".quantity").val(Quantity);` .But it doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean by "selection not changed after i continue change value in another row". I would help if you would also post the view's code.